# C#, background worker class

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

when i compile this code i get his error, object reference set to null, and the error location is in Dowork, argumenttest.valueone = 8;

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BackgroundWorker bgw1 = new BackgroundWorker();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // bgw1.RunWorkerAsync(test1);

        test test1 = new test
        {
            valueone = 5,
            valuetwo = 10
        };
        bgw1.RunWorkerAsync(test1);
    }

    class test
    {

        public int valueone { get; set; }
        public int valuetwo { get; set; }
    }

    private void bgw1_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        test argumenttest = e.Argument as test;
        Thread.Sleep(10);

        argumenttest.valueone = 8;
        argumenttest.valuetwo = 10;

        e.Result = argumenttest;
    }

    private void bgw1_RunWorkerCompleted(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        test test12 = e.Result as test;
        button1.Text = test12.valueone.ToString();// +test.valuetwo.ToString();
        //this.Text = test.valueone.ToString() + " "+ test.valuetwo.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        bgw1.DoWork += bgw1_DoWork;
        bgw1.RunWorkerCompleted += bgw1_RunWorkerCompleted;
        //bgw1.RunWorkerAsync(test);

    }
}
```

Comment: could you have used the word test any more often in your code? ;)

Comment: @ Henk HolterMan: I am just new to this background worker (threading) and i was implementing it just as a practise before i do some practical work on it.

Comment: @ pivotnig: i thought it easy :(

Comment: The problem is that the posted code a) does nothing and b) will not (cannot) produce the error mentioned. Try to post small working samples, and not waste time for everyone.

Comment: @ Henk Holterman: if i post not the proper / full code then some one request to see the code where all the function have been involved, so that is why, but i will try next time. can you tell me if i have a function the method test, so how can i call it in runasync()?

Comment: @safi: Yes, full _working_ code, including the problem. You did not get this error from this code. And note there is no space after `@` in comments.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: Ok and thanks for telling me about that comments as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two possible ways `argumenttest` ends up as `null`:

1. `argumenttest` was sent as `null` into the `RunWorkerAsync`.
2. `e.Argument as test;` `e.Argument` is something not compliant with `test`, and the `as` operator makes it `null`.

It hard to see which one, since your code example above is quite messed up.

**EDIT**

Can you confirm that your code is *exactly* as decyclone edited it? In that case, it looks fine, and should have worked as far as I can see.

Set a breakpoint on the first line of the DoWork method, and when debugging you should be easily able to see if 1. or 2. is the problem by hovering over `e.Argument` .

Comment: @ Oyvind Knobloch-Brathen: yes you are right Mr and thanks i figure it out, your comment number 1 is the answer :), i was acessing the argumenttest in do work() without making the object available to the runworkerasync(),

Comment: test t = new test();
            bgw1.RunWorkerAsync(t); this is how its now fixed, as i was missing the test object and passing null in the runworker async().

Answer (score 1):

One problem that I see is that you don't set the event handler before you run the worker, so these 2 lines

```
    bgw1.DoWork += bgw1_DoWork;
    bgw1.RunWorkerCompleted += bgw1_RunWorkerCompleted;
```

have to be called before

```
    bgw1.RunWorkerAsync(test1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should subscribe to DoWork and RunCompleted in Form load or before you make a call to RunWorkerAsync.

```
bgw1.DoWork += bgw1_DoWork;
bgw1.RunWorkerCompleted += bgw1_RunWorkerCompleted;
```

move the above lines to Form_Load from Button Click event handler.

And move `bgw1.RunWorkerAsync(test1);` to button click handler from Form Load method.